# Two DOM data sets (node lists) into fetch body variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have been experimenting the whole day and not been able to find a solution that feels like respectable code to achieve the following on front end , JS, DOM:

From the container below, class "Task" only; What is the best procedure to get all "id"-values as keys and all values of the attribute "value" as values into an object most suited to be passed into the body of a fetch POST?

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="schedule__container" id="schedule">
                <div class="days__container">
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                    <div class="day">Monday</div>
                    <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
                    <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
                    <div class="day">Thursday</div>
                    <div class="day">Friday</div>
                    <div class="day">Saturday</div>
                    <div class="day">Sunday</div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">0:00 - 0:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa0" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su0" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">1:00 - 1:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa1" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su1" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">2:00 - 2:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa2" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su2" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">3:00 - 3:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa3" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su3" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">4:00 - 4:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa4" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su4" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">5:00 - 5:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa5" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su5" value="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="part__day">
            <span class="time">6:00 - 6:59</span>
            <div class="task" id="mo6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="tu6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="we6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="th6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="fr6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="sa6" value="0"></div>
            <div class="task" id="su6" value="0"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have removed all my messy code attempts and left only the postJSON function to make the situation more readable.

```js
<script>

    <% data.forEach(element=> { %>

        document.getElementById("<%= element.ttfield %>").addEventListener("click", function() {
        mouseClick("<%= element.ttfield %>");
        })

        <% }) %>

       
        function mouseClick(elementId) {
            let elementValue = document.getElementById(elementId).getAttribute("value");
            if(elementValue == 0) {
                document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
                document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("value", 1);    
            }    else {
                document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
                document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("value", 0);                   
        }}


    async function postJSON(data) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/time-picker", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `div` elements which have the class `task` and also have an `id` attribute and `value` attribute to build your object using this query selector:

```css
div.task[id][value]
```

```js
function getTaskData() {
  const obj = {};
  for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("div.task[id][value]")) {
    obj[div.id] = div.getAttribute("value"); // Value as string
    // obj[div.id] = Number(div.getAttribute("value")); // Value as number
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(getTaskData()); // { "mo0": "0", "tu0": "0", ..., "su6": "0" }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="schedule__container" id="schedule">
    <div class="days__container">
      <span class="corner"></span>
      <div class="day">Monday</div>
      <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="day">Thursday</div>
      <div class="day">Friday</div>
      <div class="day">Saturday</div>
      <div class="day">Sunday</div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">0:00 - 0:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa0" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su0" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">1:00 - 1:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa1" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su1" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">2:00 - 2:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa2" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su2" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">3:00 - 3:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa3" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su3" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">4:00 - 4:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa4" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su4" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">5:00 - 5:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa5" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su5" value="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part__day">
      <span class="time">6:00 - 6:59</span>
      <div class="task" id="mo6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="tu6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="we6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="th6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="fr6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="sa6" value="0"></div>
      <div class="task" id="su6" value="0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: TYSM - you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a NodeList (the array of all tasks) and iterate it to create that object:

```
const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
const obj = {}

tasks.forEach(task => {
    const id = task.getAttribute('id')
    const value = task.getAttribute('value')
    obj[id] = value
})

console.log(obj) // {mo0: '0', tu0: '0', we0: '0', th0: '0', fr0: '0', …}
```

I hope this help

Comment: TYSM - the other answer came first and worked, but I upvoted you.